# Where should I place the comma in large numbers?

Tags: grammar, number, punctuation

If writing for an exclusively Chinese audience, would the number 五萬  be written as 5,0000 or 50,000?

To flesh out the question, we could consider:

- 五千      5000  or 5,000
- 五萬     5,0000 or 50,000
- 五十萬   50,0000 or 500,000
- 五百萬  500,0000  or 5,000,000

Am curious, about both text and software which is published with only a native Chinese speaking audience in mind.

Comment: Formally, it follows the western standard, i.e. 5,000 and 50,000 etc.

Comment: I think the title would be a bit more clear as "Where should a comma be placed in large numbers" rather than something so specific.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's `50 000` or `50,000`, the same as international standard.

Reference: [出版物上数字用法的规定](http://www.china-language.gov.cn/wenziguifan/shanghi/021.htm) (General rules for writing numerals in publications)

> 8    多位整数与小数: 
> ***8 Multidigit integers and decimals:***
>
> 8.1  阿拉伯数字书写的多位整数和小数的分节 
> ***8.1 Segmentations for multidigit integers and decimals written in Arabic numerals***
>
> 8.1.1  专业性科技出版物的分节法：从小数点起，向左和向右每三位数字一组，组间空四分之一个汉字(二分之一个阿拉伯数字)的位置。 
>  ***8.1.1 Segmentation rules for professional scientific publications: from the decimal point, towards the left and the right, make every three digits a group; the width of the gap between two adjacent groups should be 1/4 of a Chinese character width (or 1/2 of an Arabic numeral width).***
>
> ```
> 示例：2 748 456      3.141 592 65
> ```
>
> 8.1.2  非专业性科技出版物如排版留四分空有困难，可仍采用传统的以千分撇“,”分节的办法。小数部分不分节。四位以内的整数也可以不分节。 
>  ***8.1.2 For non-"professional scientific publications", if it is difficult to use "quarter space", the traditional segment comma "," is acceptable. Decimal part should not be segmented. Integers less than 4 digits can be either segmented or not segmented.***
>
> ```
> 示例：2,748,456    3.14159265    8703
> ```

#### Edit by Stan:

If following 8.1.1, then the `四分空`(quarter space) should be used according to the standard. Unfortunately, the standard hasn't exactly defined which space should be used. The list of spaces can be found in [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_(punctuation)#Spaces_in_Unicode). And practically, when rendering **NOT** by a monospaced font, I suggest using

- U+2005 Four-Per-Em Space, or
- U+202F Narrow No-Break Space

for the "quarter space". Specially, the "Narrow No-Break Space" is for the intention of not breaking a digit number.

Rendering results with mixed font `宋体+Calibri` via Microsoft Word are as follows:

[image: space]

and for the line-breaking case (text aligning setting: `两端对齐 Justify`)

[image: space-linebreak]
*Note that in the "Narrow No-Break Space" case, no matter how you edit the content, the number won't be break into two lines.

BTW, you can use the `Alt` and the numeric keypad to input the special space, like `Alt+8197` or `Alt+8239`.

Comment: +1 very good reference! And I refine your answer according to [the formal scanned copy](http://www.jwc.fudan.edu.cn/picture/article/67/fd/41/e19754a64d07b27764cad04b39e6/4f0c3003-a41e-45e8-a325-148986332e63.pdf) and this [wiki page](https://zh.m.wikipedia.org/zh-mo/Wikipedia:%E6%A0%BC%E5%BC%8F%E6%89%8B%E5%86%8C). Main modifications are 1) the 千分撇 is changed to a **half-width** comma; 2) `3，14159265` is not correct according to the context. It's changed to `3.14159265`.

Comment: Yet, the definition of `空四分之一个汉字(二分之一个阿拉伯数字)的位置` (the width of the space between every three digits should be 1/4 width of a Chinese character or 1/2 width of a digit) is a bit difficult to follow. See [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_(punctuation)), I suggest using the `U+2005 Four-Per-Em Space Space` if following 8.1.1, because a simple space seems too wide.

Comment: @Stan There are concepts like 全角空格,半角空格,etc, but I have no idea how to represent them in Unicode. The reference I quote is a printing standard. Your way seems better than a normal space.

Comment: If you don't mind, I'd like to help you add the rendering result via Microsoft Word to your answer :)

Comment: @Stan Of course not, that will be very nice.

Answer (score 1):

We usually just write as 50000, and sometimes follow the western standard 50,000.